# VB.net Dictionary loop

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Hey all i am in need of some help looping thru my Dictionary list. I can not seem to find the correct syntax in order to do so.

Here is my code:

```
Dim all = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
Dim info = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
Dim theShows As String = String.Empty

info!Logo = channel.SelectSingleNode(".//img").Attributes("src").Value
info!Channel = .SelectSingleNode("channel.//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(0).InnerText
info!Station = .SelectSingleNode("channel.//span[@class='channel']").ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(2).InnerText
info!Shows = From tag In channel.SelectNodes(".//a[@class='thickbox']")
            Select New With {channel.Show = tag.Attributes("title").Value, channel.Link = tag.Attributes("href").Value}

all.Add(info!Station, info.Item("Shows"))

theShows = all.Item("Shows")  '<--Doesnt work...
```

I just want to **extract** whatever is in **"Shows"** from the **all** dictionary.

[image]

Comment: @LarsTech Added that part in the code. Sorry for leaving that out!

Comment: `all.Add(info!Station, info.Item("Shows"))` – be consistent with your style, don’t change the syntax for item access within the same statement! In fact, don’t use the `.Item(…)` method at all, either write `info!Shows` or `info("Shows")`. But again, be consistent and don’t mix the styles.

Comment: When you declare a dictionary, the objects are KEY, VALUE. In your code, your keys are strings, and it will output an object. When you do "theShows = all.Item("Shows")", you're asking to pull the object that is tied to the key "Shows". Was this your intention? Because "Shows" seems to be an IEnumerable, and you're trying to assign it to a String variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code,

```
all.Add(info!Station, info.Item("Shows"))

theShows = all.Item("Shows")
```

The value of `info!Station` is being used as the KEY value in the `all` dictionary. Then you attempt to access the value using the constant string `"Shows"`. I'm not sure what your intention was but

```
theShows = all.Item(info!Station)
```

should return the value of `Shows` that was stored using the Key `info!Station`.

If you want the list of shows as a string, you can do this,

```
Dim Shows as String = ""
For Each item in theShows
    Shows &= item.Show & vbNewLine
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I get an error of **Conversion from type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator(Of HtmlNode,VB$AnonymousType_0(Of String,String))' to type 'String' is not valid.** when i change it to the **theShows = all.Item(info!Station)**

Comment: Since `info!Shows1` is originally being assigned from your Linq query which is returning a list of an Anonymous type, I would just remove the `Dim theShows As String = String.Empty` line and change `theShows = all.Item(info!Station)` to `Dim theShows = all.Item(info!Station)`

Comment: I am trying to extract the data from shows but doing it the way you suggested still takes me back to square 1. Check the image in my OP i just updated.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert a list of items into a string, which won't happen automatically. You will have to convert the object to whatever string you are expecting to see. For instance,  `MsgBox(theShows.First.Show)` in this case would display "Praise the Lord". I've added to my answer to show another example.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop like this

```
For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dict

    MsgBox(pair.Key & "  -  " & pair.Value)
Next
```

source : [VB.Net Dictionary](http://vb.net-informations.com/collections/dictionary.htm)

Winston